# How to get database server name in springboot

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, spring-boot

I want to execute a stored procedure based on the server name in am spring boot application

Below is the stored proc.

```
  @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "EXEC sys.sp_wait_for_database_copy_sync  @target_server = N'sql-secondary', @target_database = N'sql-primary'")
  @Transactional
  public void spWaitForDatabaseCopy();
```

I want to execute this query only if current server is primary. How can I achieve this springboot java ?

I tried below code to get the server name:

```
  @Query(value = "SELECT  @@SERVERNAME AS 'Server Name' ")
    public String getServerName();
```

but I see error at @.  or DISTINCT expected, got '@'

Is there better way to get the server name and then execute stored proc based on the result?

Comment: I don't know springboot but why doesn't your second query have `nativeQuery = true`? Did you try `SELECT [Server Name] = @@SERVERNAME;`? Seems your application is trying to parse the SQL before submitting it, and `AS 'alias'` is not the best form. Also, `only if current server is primary` -> what are you checking the server name against? Why not just use [`sys.fn_hadr_is_primary_replica`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-hadr-is-primary-replica-transact-sql)?

Comment: yes, I missed adding nativeQuery to second one,

Comment: You can just use one batch `IF 0 = ( SELECT role FROM master.sys.geo_replication_links WHERE database_id = DB_ID() ) EXEC sys.sp_wait_for_database_copy_sync  ....`

Comment: yes, I was looking for something like this. Thanks, It worked.

Comment: but I want to achieve this using spring boot: Wondering what will be the entity for for the sys queries ?